# how to ignore folders in melos packages

Tags: flutter, dart, monorepo, melos

working in a monorepo with this structure

```bash
monorepo/
  examples/
    # ...
    foo/
  packages/
    # ...
    foo/
      # ...
      example/ -> examples/foo/
```

where the `example` in `packages/foo`
is a deep link to `examples/foo/`
that contains a demo app called `foo_example`

I'm encountering a problem during [melos](https://melos.invertase.dev/) bootstrap

```
Run melos bootstrap
melos.yaml: Multiple packages with the name `foo_example` found in the workspace, which is unsupported.
To fix this problem, consider renaming your packages to have a unique name.

The packages that caused the problem are:
- foo_example at packages/foo/example
- foo_example at examples/foo

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I would like to keep the folders for `examples` and `packages` separated
while providing an `example` readily available for `https://pub.dev/`

#### is there a way to exclude the `packages/**/example/` folders from [melos](https://pub.dev/packages/melos)?

this is how I'm pointing at the packages right now

```yaml
name: <my_mono_repo>

packages:
  - examples/**
  - packages/**

scripts:
 # ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always read the docs :)
https://melos.invertase.dev/configuration/overview#ignore

this does the job

```yaml
ignore:
  # e.g. ignore example apps
  - "packages/**/example"
```